# Sum numbers on string

Tags: c#, string

Am using C#
I have string of numbers  that are separate with ','like ...

"3,2,2,1,2,1,2"

I want to sum the numbers on the string , how to do that ...in simple way ?
3+2+2+1+2+1+2=13

any idea ?

here my code ...my string is SupplierAnswer but it dose not work

**Grad is Int** 
**SupplierAnswer is string**

```
      StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder();

        if (_Project.ProjectRequirements != null)
        {
            foreach (Requiernments Req in _Project.ProjectRequirements)
            {
                strb.Append(Req.SupplierAnswer + ",");
                this.AddRequirement(Req);
            }

            this.SupplierAnswers = strb.ToString();

           this.Grad = SupplierAnswers.Split(',').Select(c => int.Parse(c)).Sum(); 



            this.SupplierAnswers =   this.SupplierAnswers.Remove(this.SupplierAnswers.Length - 1);
        }
```

Comment: In particular, separate this one task into three: splitting the string on commas, parsing each part of the string as an integer, and then summing the integers.

Comment: Use regex to split out the numbers into a collection then iterate through the collection and add up the contents.

Comment: I don't see how google did not help you. Look for "parse string", "split string" .. and "string to int" with additional "C#" ..

Comment: @Bobby Why on earth would you recommend regex for this?

Comment: @VahidND [give a man a fish...](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime).

Comment: @DGibbs because I saw a pattern...... and forgot about the split function

Comment: @Bobby Fair enough. Regex would be the last thing to spring to mind for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `Split` to separate your string into many strings, and then use `Int32.Parse` to convert these strings to integer. Then, use the `Sum` method to this list of integer.

Very simple with Linq !

```
String example = "3,2,2,1,2,1,2";
Int32 sum = example.Split(new char[] { ',' })   // get the "list" of strings
                   .Select(n => Int32.Parse(n)) // get the "list" of integers
                   .Sum();                      // get the sum
```

Comment: thank my solution work ....the problem that I had "," at the end ...I have to remove it before I convert it ...and I was doing the opposite ....Anyway , i made this as an answer coz is also valid :)

Comment: one small question If I want to add values for each integer like...First intger like if 3 +10 if 2+5 if 1+ 0 .... how to do that ???